# Python 3 text files - I want to add add user input to the end of each line of text in file 1 then copy the new lines into file 2

Tags: python, text-files

File1 contains 5 lines with text
File2 is empty
Q.  when I run the code below I only get the first 4 lines appended to File2?
Any suggestions?

```
        File1 = open("MyFile.txt", "r")

        for Line in File1:
            Line = Line.strip()
            AddData = input( "extra text")
            NewLine = Line + ":" + AddData  # : as field seperator
            File2 = open("MyFile2.txt", "a")
            File2.write(NewLine+"\n")
            print(NewLine) #remove

        File2.close
```

Comment: I do not see any error here. All the five lines should get added. Please see if Myfile.txt contains 5 lines.

Comment: Have you been asked for "extra text" 5 or 4 times? Also: there's no need to reopen File2 before each write, you should have done it **before** entering the loop.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply:  There are 5 lines of text in File1 and yes I am asked for the extra text 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not closing the file write
You need to use:

```
 File2.close()
```

and not

```
File2.close
```

Without the parenthesis you only name the function without actually calling it and then it is not executed

And the write(newline) method is only passing your line to a buffer, it's write to file only when buffer is full or when you call open() or close()
Your first 4 lines were written because you called the open() method after them